# Error running storyboards on Xamarin in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: ios, .net, macos, xamarin, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to preview the Main.storyboard file in a Xamarin Classic app that I've just created using Visual Studio 2019. It doesn't work and gives an error message. Google hasn't been much help for this.

I have paired my Windows 10 laptop to the Mac Mini in my living room using Visual Studio, and there is an active connection to it. However, I'm not able to run the iOS simulator on Windows (always says there's a 'fatal error') so I've tested the app on iOS on the Mac itself.

Here is the error message:

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> MonoTouch.Design.Client.InvalidSessionException: Error in the application.
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.SendRequest(CommandRequest req, Boolean throwIfNotRunning) in E:\A\_work\283\s\Xamarin.Designer.iOS\MonoTouch.Design.Client\Connection\ServerProcessConnection.cs:line 235
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.SendRequest[TResponse](CommandRequest req, Boolean throwIfNotRunning) in E:\A\_work\283\s\Xamarin.Designer.iOS\MonoTouch.Design.Client\Connection\ServerProcessConnection.cs:line 252
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.CreateSession() in E:\A\_work\283\s\Xamarin.Designer.iOS\MonoTouch.Design.Client\Connection\ServerProcessConnection.cs:line 111
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.<CreateSessionAsync>b__28_0() in E:\A\_work\283\s\Xamarin.Designer.iOS\MonoTouch.Design.Client\Connection\ServerProcessConnection.cs:line 116
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.IPhoneDesignerSession.<>c__DisplayClass289_1`1.<EnsureSession>b__1(Task`1 t) in E:\A\_work\283\s\Xamarin.Designer.iOS\MonoTouch.Design.Client\IPhoneDesignerSession.cs:line 2072
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.IPhoneDesignerSession.<>c__DisplayClass289_0`1.<EnsureSession>b__0() in E:\A\_work\283\s\Xamarin.Designer.iOS\MonoTouch.Design.Client\IPhoneDesignerSession.cs:line 2146
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.IPhoneDesignerSession.<RenderXmlWithPartialReloadRetry>d__191.MoveNext() in E:\A\_work\283\s\Xamarin.Designer.iOS\MonoTouch.Design.Client\IPhoneDesignerSession.cs:line 750
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.IPhoneDesignerSession.<RenderXmlWithPartialReloadRetry>d__191.MoveNext() in E:\A\_work\283\s\Xamarin.Designer.iOS\MonoTouch.Design.Client\IPhoneDesignerSession.cs:line 757
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.IPhoneDesignerSession.<RenderXml>d__190.MoveNext() in E:\A\_work\283\s\Xamarin.Designer.iOS\MonoTouch.Design.Client\IPhoneDesignerSession.cs:line 735
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.IPhoneDesignerSession.<RenderXml>d__190.MoveNext() in E:\A\_work\283\s\Xamarin.Designer.iOS\MonoTouch.Design.Client\IPhoneDesignerSession.cs:line 743
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.IPhoneDesignerSession.<ReloadItemsAsync>d__186.MoveNext() in E:\A\_work\283\s\Xamarin.Designer.iOS\MonoTouch.Design.Client\IPhoneDesignerSession.cs:line 624
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MonoTouch.Design.Tasks.<Cancellable>d__1.MoveNext() in E:\A\_work\283\s\Xamarin.Designer.iOS\MonoTouch.Design.Shared\TaskExtensions.cs:line 28
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.IPhoneDesignerSession.<ReloadItems>d__185.MoveNext() in E:\A\_work\283\s\Xamarin.Designer.iOS\MonoTouch.Design.Client\IPhoneDesignerSession.cs:line 576
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> MonoTouch.Design.Client.InvalidSessionException: Error in the application.
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.SendRequest(CommandRequest req, Boolean throwIfNotRunning) in E:\A\_work\283\s\Xamarin.Designer.iOS\MonoTouch.Design.Client\Connection\ServerProcessConnection.cs:line 235
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.SendRequest[TResponse](CommandRequest req, Boolean throwIfNotRunning) in E:\A\_work\283\s\Xamarin.Designer.iOS\MonoTouch.Design.Client\Connection\ServerProcessConnection.cs:line 252
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.CreateSession() in E:\A\_work\283\s\Xamarin.Designer.iOS\MonoTouch.Design.Client\Connection\ServerProcessConnection.cs:line 111
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.<CreateSessionAsync>b__28_0() in E:\A\_work\283\s\Xamarin.Designer.iOS\MonoTouch.Design.Client\Connection\ServerProcessConnection.cs:line 116
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.IPhoneDesignerSession.<>c__DisplayClass289_1`1.<EnsureSession>b__1(Task`1 t) in E:\A\_work\283\s\Xamarin.Designer.iOS\MonoTouch.Design.Client\IPhoneDesignerSession.cs:line 2072
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
---> (Inner Exception #0) MonoTouch.Design.Client.InvalidSessionException: Error in the application.
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.SendRequest(CommandRequest req, Boolean throwIfNotRunning) in E:\A\_work\283\s\Xamarin.Designer.iOS\MonoTouch.Design.Client\Connection\ServerProcessConnection.cs:line 235
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.SendRequest[TResponse](CommandRequest req, Boolean throwIfNotRunning) in E:\A\_work\283\s\Xamarin.Designer.iOS\MonoTouch.Design.Client\Connection\ServerProcessConnection.cs:line 252
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.CreateSession() in E:\A\_work\283\s\Xamarin.Designer.iOS\MonoTouch.Design.Client\Connection\ServerProcessConnection.cs:line 111
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.<CreateSessionAsync>b__28_0() in E:\A\_work\283\s\Xamarin.Designer.iOS\MonoTouch.Design.Client\Connection\ServerProcessConnection.cs:line 116
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)<---
<---
```

Comment: Hi , **First** disconnecting with Mac, and forget this Mac. **Second** rebooting the Mac  . **Last** reconnecting to Mac with username and password to check whehter it works .

Comment: Hi, didn't work. What now?

Comment: Okey , whehter it's a new created project to check that ?